# Feature toggle for scala

Tags: scala, sbt, chisel, featuretoggle

I'm developing a scala project and I need to print some debugging info when I'm testing the program. I've put some print function in the middle of the program. But I just want to run them if I have activated some debug flag or something like that.

I couldn't find a clean way to do what I want. I wonder if there is anything which I can use?

Just to explain more about my project, I'm using Chisel library which generates hardware and for building I'm using SBT.

Comment: why not just use a standard logging library like logback?

Comment: You could just use a Boolean if it's a temporary need. If you want something cleaner, you should look at a logging solution such as log4j which supports configurable levels of logging.

Comment: Do you mean printing during elaboration time or printing when the circuit is simulating?

Comment: @jkoenig yes I want to enable/disable simulation print statements

Comment: Other than the very rudimentary `printf(...)` support, there is currently no logging library for simulation. There is a feature-request issue filed on the chisel3 repo you can watch to see when such support is available (there is also an ugly workaround idea provided): https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel3/issues/435

Answer (score 2):

Usually it is solved by logging. Take a look at [Scala Logging](https://github.com/typesafehub/scala-logging)

You write in code log statements with different level of severity

```
logger.debug("This is very convenient ;-)")

...
logger.error("Something is really wrong")
```

Then before running application chose which level of messages you want to see. Usually warnings and error in normal scenarios or debug messages when debugging

Comment: Unfortunately this answer is not really what the user wants. Chisel is a DSL that constructs a hardware AST that can then be emitted and simulated. The user wants a logging library that works at simulation time which does not exist at the moment.